# Extracting certain files from a tar archive on a remote ssh server

Tags: bash, ssh, tar

I am running numerous simulations on a remote server (via ssh). The outcomes of these simulations are stored as .tar archives in an archive directory on this remote server.

What I would like to do, is write a bash script which connects to the remote server via ssh and extracts the required output files from each .tar archive into separate folders on my local hard drive.

These folders should have the same name as the .tar file from which the files come (To give an example, say the output of simulation 1 is stored in the archive S1.tar on the remote server, I want all '.dat' and '.def' files within this .tar archive to be extracted to a directory S1 on my local drive).

For the extraction itself, I was trying:

```
for f in *.tar; do
(
    mkdir ../${f%.tar}
    tar -x -f "$f" -C ../${f%.tar} "*.dat" "*.def"
)
done
wait
```

Every .tar file is around 1GB and there is a lot of them. So downloading everything takes too much time, which is why I only want to extract the necessary files (see the extensions in the code above).

Now the code works perfectly when I have the .tar files on my local drive. However, what I can't figure out is how I can do it without first having to download all the .tar archives from the server.

When I first connect to the remote server via `ssh username@host`, then the terminal stops with the script and just connects to the server.

Btw I am doing this in VS Code and running the script through terminal on my MacBook.

I hope I have described it clear enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You lost me at "I can't figure out is how I can do it without first having to download all the .tar archives from the server". Why not run the script on the server, tar the resulting directory and `scp` that to local?

Comment: If you want to get _fancy_, you could even write the script such that you can pipe it to SSH, output the tar archive via SSH's stdout, and pipe that to tar to decompress it locally.

Comment: Add `--wildcards` before `"*.dat"` to enable wildcards with GNU tar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Stream the results of `tar` back with filenames via SSH

To get the data you wish to retrieve from `.tar` files, you'll need to pass the results of `tar` to a string of commands with the [`--to-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html#SEC87) option. In the example below, we'll run three commands.

```sh
# Send the files name back to your shell
echo $TAR_FILENAME

# Send the contents of the file back
cat /dev/stdin

# Send EOF (Ctrl+d) back (note: since we're already in a $'' we don't use the $ again)
echo '\004'
```

Once the information is captured in your shell, we can start to process the data. This is a three-step process.

1. **Get the file's name**

   - note that, in this code, we aren't handling directories at all (simply stripping them away; i.e. `dir/1.dat -> 1.dat`)
   - you can write code to create directories for the file by replacing the forward slashes `/` with spaces and iterating over each directory name but that seems out-of-scope for this.
2. **Check for the EOF** (end-of-file)
3. **Add content to file**

```sh
# Get the files via ssh and tar
files=$(ssh -n <user@server> $'tar -xf <tar-file> --wildcards \'*\' --to-command=$\'echo $TAR_FILENAME; cat /dev/stdin; echo \'\004\'\'')

# Keeps track of what state we're in (filename or content)
state="filename"
filename=""

# Each line is one of these:
#  - file's name
#  - file's data
#  - EOF
while read line; do
  if [[ $state == "filename" ]]; then
    filename=${line/*\//}
    touch $filename
    echo "Copying: $filename"
    state="content"
  elif [[ $state == "content" ]]; then
    # look for EOF (ctrl+d)
    if [[ $line == $'\004' ]]; then
      filename=""
      state="filename"
    else
      # append data to file
      echo $line >> <output-folder>/$filename
    fi
  fi
# Double quotes here are very important
done < <(echo -e "$files")
```

---

## Alternative: `tar` + `scp`

If the above example seems overly complex for what it's doing, it is. An alternative that touches the disk more and requires to separate ssh connections would be to extract the files you need from your `.tar` file to a folder and `scp` that folder back to your workstation.

```sh
ssh -n <username>@<server> 'mkdir output/; tar -C output/ -xf <tar-file> --wildcards *.dat *.def'
scp -r <username>@<server>:output/ ./
```

#### The breakdown

First, we'll make a place to keep our outputted files. You can skip this if you already know the folder they'll be in.

```sh
mkdir output/
```

Then, we'll extract the matching files to this folder we created (if you don't want them to be in a different folder remove the `-C output/` option).

```sh
tar -C output/ -xf <tar-file> --wildcards *.dat *.def
```

Lastly, now that we're running commands on our machine again, we can run `scp` to reconnect to the remote machine and pull the files back.

```sh
scp -r <username>@<server>:output/ ./
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the the detailed explanation. I will try the alternative.

Comment: I realized the first option only works without spaces in files, I'm fixing that now with a read-while loop